# Relative links and backbone.js router

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

I'm using the router function in backbone.js and came across this problem. This may be a trivial thing, but I cant seem to figure this out nor find anything on Google.

**Problem:** On the page `http://www.mydomain.com/user/1` there is a link. This link should link to `http://www.mydomain.com/user/1/profile`.

Of course if I use `<a href="1/profile">` I get what I am looking for, but `1` is a dynamically generated value. How then should my router define the routes? I believe its not a wise choice to hardcode the number `1` into the routes.

```
//Router

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        '': 'profile',
        'profile': 'profile'
    },

    profile: function() {

    }
});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

When I set the `href` attribute of the `a` tag like `<a href="profile">`, the link that results is `http://www.mydomain.com/user/profile`.

For `<a href="./profile">` I get `http://www.mydomain.com/user/profile`.

For `<a href="/profile">` I get `http://www.mydomain.com/profile`.

For `<a href="profile/">` I get `http://www.mydomain.com/profile/`.

Why is the `1` missing, and how can I keep it to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define this dynamic URLs directly in the HTML, you have to create them into your Views.

For example:

**template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-element">
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <a class="profile" href="<%= url_profile %>">profile</a>
</script>
```

**js code:**

```
// code simplified and no tested
var Element = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    this.set( "url_profile", this.url() + "/profile" );
  }
});

var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#template-element").html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    return this;
  }
});
```

Or, as I do sometimes when I feel in the way:

**template:**

```
<script type="text/template" id="template-element">
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <a class="profile" href="#replace_with_real_url">profile</a>
</script>
```

**js code:**

```
// no Element.url_profile attribute needed:
var ElementView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( $("#template-element").html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
    this.$el.find( ".profile" ).attr( "href", "/user/" + this.model.id + "/profile" );
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

as you can see in http://backbonejs.org/#Router, you can use parameters in your routes, as in `'/user/:id/profile'`

Comment: Thanks, how do I get a link to point to `/user/1/profile` by including a relative path? The `:id` keeps disappearing in the link generated so I end up wiwth `/user/profile`